# Replacing Slang using a dictionary

Tags: python

I have been following this link in oder to solve my problem but I got stuck along the way: [Issues with replacing words in a string using a dictionary and the replace() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172625/issues-with-replacing-words-in-a-string-using-a-dictionary-and-the-replace-fun[]).

I have a series with more that 20 000 rows, each row with string of text(short messeges). And a dictionary of keys and values, such  that I want to replace my series word with a value in the dictionary whenever the series word  matches a key in the dictionary:

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
dictionary = {'u': 'you','pic':'picture', .....} 

list_string = the_string['message'].str.split()

for i,word in enumerate(list_string):
    if word in the_dictionary.keys():
        list_string[i] = the_dictionary[word]
```

When I run this code I don't get errors except that the series doesn't get updated. What am I missing? I am still learning python, so I got stuck here.

Comment: You do not close your string in the first code fragment. Please first fix your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem- ok

Comment: What does not get updated, the list `list_string` or the original string `the_string['message']`? It should update the list. For the string, use `' '.join(list_string)`

Comment: BTW, you loop could be simplified to `list_string = [the_dictionary.get(word, word) for word in list_string]`

Comment: @tobias: list_string

Answer (score 0):

> When run this I don't get errors except that the series doesn't get updated.

What exactly is not getting updated? `list_string` or `the_string`? 'Cause putting aside the fact that you declare `dictionary` and then use `the_dictionary` in the loop, it does update `list_string` on my end. If you want `the_string` to also get updated, then you'd also need to update it — you can do so like this:

```
the_string = " ".join(list_string)
```

Note, however, that your current check does not account for capitalization, which means you'd fix `u` into `you`, but `U` would not get turned into `You`.